# Scrolling in iOS for a component with variable height

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I am trying to make a vertically scrolling view, where the screen has three sections and scrolls up or down in totality (i.e. all the three sections move up and together together)

[image: Vertical Scrolling]

There are three parts of the screen - Section 1, 2 are fixed height and section 3 is scrollable depending on the number of row data that the server sends to the client

How do I achieve this in iOS - is there a way of having

1. Parent View

   - Section 1
   - Section 2
   - Section 3

and then call scrolling function on the Parent View? I don't want to go into the messy details of manually adjusting the height of the Parent View by checking the Section 3 height (variable) and adjusting accordingly - surely there is a way in iOS programming to encapsulate all this behaviour in a clean little class. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

This behavior can be realized with native iOS components.

There can be different implementations but I would choose this one:

- UITableView

  - HeaderView

    - UIView (Section 1)
    - UIView (Section 2)
  - Content View (Section 3)

    - UITableViewCell (Section 3 cell representing your first row data)
    - ...

In Xcode Interface Builder, you can add an header view by dragging a view on top of the displayed prototype cell.

With this architecture, the HeaderView will have a fixed height, and the ContentView will have a dynamic height. And when you scroll, the whole UITableView will scroll.